# What video card will support four monitors without Xinerama?

Tags: x11, opensuse, multi-monitor

I'm running OpenSuse 12.3 and currently have two NVIDIA video cards spanning four monitors. The problem I have is performance since Xinerama can't utilize the hardware acceleration.

There are lots of video cards that will support four monitors but will I be able to have a single desktop spanned across four screens without using Xinerama?

The answer I'm hoping for is, "yes, I have *** card running 3|4 monitors with full hardware acceleration."

Answer (score 1):

I purchased another card in an attempt to get what I wanted working, and it does! That card is an ATI Radeon HD 6970 with two DVI's and two active mini display ports. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814202035

I currently have three monitors running with the performance I expected on Ubuntu 12.04. This was a true plug and play experience.

Now I will have to take the card to work and see how OpenSuse 12.3 handles it with four monitors.

Comment: Here is a link to my Google+ post and picture of it at work: https://plus.google.com/110264306527919991460/posts/TfxjCHotmyn